# How to position an icon in a <li>?

Tags: css

I have a problem, I am trying to relocate the "fa-chevron-down" icon justified to the right with a 20px padding

Example:

[image]

HTML:

```
 <nav id="nav-menu" class="nav-menu">
        <ul id="ul-accordion" class="ul-accordion">
            <li>
                <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-html5"></i>Emploplyee<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Add</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Delate</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-html5"></i>Payment<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Add</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Delate</a></li>
                    <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

[Run Link Code](https://jsfiddle.net/rqhb1rtn/1/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rqhb1rtn/3/ see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/4y0LL5en/1/)

Not much different from the solution in previous answer:

```
.ul-accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
    font-size: 16px;
    float:right;
    padding:0 20px;   
}
```

***But*** I added some animation of the chevrons that behave like a typical dropdown icon:

This at the top block of jQuery:

```
$("i.fa.fa-chevron-down").addClass('fa-rotate-270');
```

and this at the bottom:

```
$(this).find('i.fa.fa-chevron-down').toggleClass('fa-rotate-270');
```

**Note:** if `.fa-chevron-down` was omitted here, the `.fa-html5` would also rotate which looks kinda cool...

**The 3 minor changes are commented in demo**

### Demo

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".submenu").slideUp();
    $(".link").addClass('Close'); 
    
    // Start the chevron pointing to the right
    $("i.fa.fa-chevron-down").addClass('fa-rotate-270');
    
    $(".link").on('click', function () {
        
        if ($(this).is(".Close")) {
            $(this).removeClass('Close');
            $(this).next(".submenu").slideDown();
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('Close');
            $(this).next(".submenu").slideUp();
        }
        
        /* When toggling, the correct state is 
        || always executed at the correct alternation
        || as long as class is correctly set
        || before loading page.
        */
        $(this).find('i.fa.fa-chevron-down').toggleClass('fa-rotate-270');
    })
});
```

```css
.nav-menu {
    max-width: 350px;
    background-color:white;
}

.ul-accordion {
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.ul-accordion li {
    list-style-type: none;

}

.ul-accordion li i {
    color: green;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.ul-accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
    font-size: 16px;
/* Added for right justification and requested padding */
    float:right;
    padding:0 20px;   
}

.ul-accordion li i.fa-paint-brush {
    left: 35px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
}

.submenu {
    padding: 0px;
}

.submenu ul {
    
    padding: 0px;
}

.submenu li{

    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.link {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f8e0e376c3.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav id="nav-menu" class="nav-menu">
            <ul id="ul-accordion" class="ul-accordion">
                <li>
                    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-html5"></i>Emploplyee<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Add</a></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <div class="link"><i class="fa fa-html5"></i>Payment<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></div>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Add</a></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Edit</a></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i><a href="#">Search</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
  
  </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

float it to the right and add a 20px right margin

```
.ul-accordion li i.fa-chevron-down {
    font-size: 16px;
    float:right;
    margin-right:20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rqhb1rtn/2/